# Bulk loader fails with "Backing off due to errors"

Tags: google-app-engine

**Background:**

I have a small application (just one model) developed on Google App Engine (Python) running fine on my dev server. I am running my app server like this:

```
python "c:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\dev_appserver.py" --default_partition="" -a 0.0.0.0 my_app
```

I have around 30k entries in my model. I want to upload these entries to my app deployed on appspot. I have enabled remote_api by entering this in my app.yaml:

```
builtins:
  - remote_api: on
  - datastore_admin: on
```

I started by exporting these entries using this command:

```
python "c:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\appcfg.py" download_data --filename=localhost.csv --url=http://localhost:8080/_ah/remote_api/ --kind=MyModel
```

**Problem:**

The export goes fine for a while (i.e. I can see progress as dots) but after sometime I start getting this error:

```
[INFO    ] [WorkerThread-X] Backing off due to errors: 2.0 seconds
```

where X is a random integer between 1 and 8
This error never stops, even after hours. I cannot see anything wrong in log of dev_appserver.py

Comment: Did you ever find out what was causing this?  Is this still an issue?  If so, how long does the script run before throwing these errors?